# How can I compare Generic Type and Double

Tags: swift, dictionary, generics, compare, double

I'm trying to write generic function to compare computed value with some values in dictionary of type [String: (Double, Double)].

The computed value has type Double, but if the application will be extended and appears some new computed value with another type this function could be reused. But I cant compare Double type with Generic, what should I change to solve this ?

```
let angleDict = ["Snatch": (-1.0, -0.9962),
                 "Thruster": (-1.0, -0.9962),
                 "Ringdip": (0.0, 0.9998),
                 "Burpee": (0.1736, 0.9998),
                 "Push Up": (0.0, 0.9998),
                 "Back Squat": (0.0, 0.9998)]

func probeResult<T: Numeric & Comparable>(exerciseName: String, cosAngle: T) -> String{
    return cosAngle > angleDict[exerciseName]!.0 && cosAngle < angleDict[exerciseName]!.1 ? "OK" : "WRONG"
}
```

Comment: is value is going to double every time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `BinaryFloatingPoint` Protocol instead of  Numeric to be able to coerce its value to Double, create a range and check if it contains your cosAngle (Note: Comparable constraint can be removed considering that contains doesn't require the Element to be Comparable, only Equatable):

```
func probeResult<T: BinaryFloatingPoint>(exerciseName: String, cosAngle: T) -> Bool {
    guard
        let lower = angleDict[exerciseName]?.0.nextUp,
        let upper = angleDict[exerciseName]?.1
        else { return false }
    return lower..<upper ~= Double(cosAngle)
    // or
    // return T(lower)..<T(upper) ~= cosAngle
}
```

---

```
let result = probeResult(exerciseName: "Back Squat", cosAngle: CGFloat(0.5))  ? "OK" : "WRONG"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried as like below?

```
func probeResult<T: Numeric & Comparable>(exerciseName: String, cosAngle: T) -> String{

        var d = 0.0

        switch cosAngle {
        case let value as Int:
            d = Double(value)
        case let value as Int32:
            d = Double(value)
        case let value as Double:
            d = value
        default:
            break
        }

        return d > angleDict[exerciseName]!.0 && d < angleDict[exerciseName]!.1 ? "OK" : "WRONG"
    }
```

Comment: No I haven't, I'm trying it now and in first two cases compiler says that cast always fails